# How to install phpMyAdmin to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I run command:  `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` to install phpMyAdmin.

Then I enter address: localhost/phpmyadmin/ but I cannot see anything so I followed this thread:

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15515
Now when I enter address localhost/phpmyadmin/ browser want to download some PHTML file (5.7 KB)

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

Also check apache service should be running, if not so run

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or install apache

```
sudo apt-get install apache
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the message `Package 'phpmyadmin' has no installation candidate`, try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

**But, firstly, check if you have the MySQL installed:**

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

If not, install it with:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```